# How to write the schema for the below object in Realm dataBase react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, realm-migration

I am trying to write a schema for the object given below. but, I can't insert the data by using it. can anyone help me to fix it? I have tried for it for one day.

```js
[{job_number:"142323",
        ord_obj_guid:"fdsvghfsdgkh123123c2-dnhfgsdjf",
        client_order_id:"34235435",
        customer:{
          first_name:"ravi",
          last_name:"maddukuri",
          phone_numbers:[{ 
                phone_number:"11235448545",
                phone_type:"home"
             }],
          email:"ravi@hdfj.dku",
          address1:"23423  r etre",
          address2:"rewtert etert",
          city:"erter e t",
          state:"ertertert",
          zip:"25436854"
        },
        {job_number:"215423323",
        ord_obj_guid:"fdsvghfsdgkh123123c2-dnhfgsdjf",
        client_order_id:"34235435",
        customer:{
          first_name:"krish",
          last_name:"krishna",
          phone_numbers:[{ 
                phone_number:"11235448545",
                phone_type:"home"
             }],
          email:"krish@hdfj.dku",
          address1:"23423  r etre",
          address2:"rewtert etert",
          city:"erter e t",
          state:"ertertert",
          zip:"25436854"
        }]
```